# Is there a way to burn honeypot tokens in a wallet

Tags: erc-20

There are some tokens in my wallet which are honeypot tokens and I can't sell them or transfer them, is there a way to burn them or are they stuck in my wallet forever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to burn them or are they stuck in my wallet forever?

They are stuck there forever.